# How to show all folder sizes of Android phone in Windows file explorer?

Tags: windows, android, storage, disk-space

When I run space analysis it shows about 50GB of others, and I don't what is that exactly, so I wanted to manage the space on file explorer on windows 11, but the thing is it doesn't show the folder & file sizes. So how can I manage the internal storage of the android phone on windows?

Phone: Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) SM-530F

Android Version: 9.0

Comment: You should [edit] your question to indicate what version of WIndows you are using.  Try and avoid using random tags like "storage spaces" since that topic has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Is this even a supported function of the transfer protocol? I've always found it more efficient to use [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) to get directory size info via `du -sh /sdcard/path/to/directory` _(can be directly shown by prefacing with [`adb shell`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands), otherwise issue `adb shell` first to access Android's terminal)_

Comment: https://github.com/ivanvolosyuk/diskusage & https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247287/44325